# Google App JDBC.getConnection failed with error Exception: Connection URL uses an unsupported JDBC protocol

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-sql

I am writing a simple script in Apps Script to connect to a database created in Cloud SQL on Google, but my script failed syntax checking on this line:

```js
var conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection(instanceUrl,"root","");
```

The error says: `Exception: Connection URL uses an unsupported JDBC protocol. (line 8, file "Code")`

Why?

Comment: Hi there @gxu! I couldn't reproduce this behaviour, could you please share how we all can replicate this issue? To prevent any misconfiguration, please try to create a new database as detailed [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs). To better clarify this issue, are you using Cloud SQL, MySQL or PostgreSQL?